# Select the resource for findViewById(R.id.xxx) in code

Tags: android

This is my first post, sorry for the title and the explication. Sorry for my English.

I define an .xml with all I need. I have 10 ImageView and the id for 10 ImageView are myimage01, myimage02, ... , myimage010.
I need to select an image for an ImageView.
I can do it as follows:

```
String imageName=getImageName();      
  id = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getPackageName());
  drawable = res.getDrawable(id);
  ImageView cant1= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage01);
  cant1.setImageDrawable(drawable);
  ImageView cant2= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage02);
  cant2.setImageDrawable(drawable);
  ImageView cant3= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage03);
  cant3.setImageDrawable(drawable);
  ImageView cant4= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage04);
  cant4.setImageDrawable(drawable); 
  ImageView cant5= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage05);
  cant5.setImageDrawable(drawable);
  ImageView cant6= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage06);
  cant6.setImageDrawable(drawable);
  ImageView cant7= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage07);
  cant7.setImageDrawable(drawable);
  ImageView cant8= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage08);
  cant8.setImageDrawable(drawable);
  ImageView cant9= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage09);
  cant9.setImageDrawable(drawable);
  ImageView cant10= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage010);
  cant10.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

But this is too bad, its better to use a loop. But I don't know do this.

I need something like that:

```
    String cad;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      cad="myimage0";
      String cat= Integer.toString(i);
      cad=cad.concat(cat);
      ImageView cant1= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cad);
      cant1.setImageDrawable(drawable);
  }
```

But there is an error in:

```
ImageView cant1= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.***cad***);
```

Thanks for all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't directly pass in a String like that to `findViewById`. You'll need to look up the resource from your String first. Try this:

```
int idResource = getResources().getIdentifier(cad, "id", getPackageName());
ImageView cant1= (ImageView)findViewById(idResource);
```

Comment: how fast!!!
**MANY THANKS for your help!**
I've tried with your code and your help and works perfect!
A greeting from Spain!!
=)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in a loop:

```
getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "id", getPackageName());
```

Where resName is exact string for that id (in your example, it's myimage01, myimage02, ...

so we have:

```
String cad;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      cad="myimage0";
      String cat= Integer.toString(i);
      cad=cad.concat(cat);
      int id = getResources().getIdentifier(cad, "id", getPackageName());
      ImageView cant1= (ImageView)findViewById(id);
      cant1.setImageDrawable(drawable);
  }
```

Comment: how fast!!!
**MANY THANKS for your help!**
I've tried with your code and your help and works perfect!
A greeting from Spain!!
=)